# Knockout observable not triggering when using throttle

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have the following:

```
self.periodicallySave = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.optionA() || self.optionB() || self.optionC()) {
        self.saveOptions();
    }
}).extend({ throttle: 1000 });
```

I'm using this computed to periodically save text fields as they update.  Those text fields are `textareas` and look like this:

```
    <textarea rows="2" data-bind="textInput: optionA"></textarea>
```

With the exception of `optionA` which is a `select`.

```
            <select data-bind="value: optionA">
                <option>Foo</option>
                <option>Bar</option>
            </select>
```

For some reason, only `OptionA` triggers my computed observable; changing the others has no effect.  Am I misunderstanding how computed observables work?  My expectation is that if any of those observables change, the function will be triggered.

**Update:**

If I use a `+` instead of a `||`, it works as expected.  Odd that OR seems to stop the observable chain; especially since `optionA` is a `select` that can only ever contain one of two values.  Removing `optionA` also yields expected results.

Comment: What happens if you add a `console.log("foo");` just inside the computed and then exercise the UI inputs? Any errors in the console? All the resources returning HTTP 200 in the network portion of developer tools?

Comment: @DaveB - just added an update.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What version of knockout are you using? Throttle was deprecated in 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has to do with the way knockout sets up the change tracking dependencies for the computed function. Your 3 option observables are all within an IF statement and therefore if the first option starts as true, the second two conditions get short circuited and are not evaluated. Since they aren't evaluated knockout never binds to them.

A computed observable used this way is a little bit dangerous in my opinion because it often has unexpected side effects. You can easily "fix" this behavior by unwrapping the observables into variables first before checking their values:

```
self.periodicallySave = ko.computed(function () {
    var a = self.optionA();
    var b = self.optionB();
    var c = self.optionC();

    if (self.optionA() || self.optionB() || self.optionC()) {
        self.saveOptions();
    }
  }).extend({ throttle: 1000 });
```

but I think it might be a little cleaner (although less concise) to set up subscriptions to each of the observables instead.

Comment: Thank you - can you set up subscriptions with throttling?  I haven't found any examples.  I also love how little code this approach requires to do what I need - saving a collection of items max once per second as any of them change.

Comment: You can subscribe to a throttled observable, which has the same effect. I'm not completely sure how that would work out with 3 separate throttled observables though so I'll have to test it out and see what the result looks like.

Comment: @user666 Here's a version using subscriptions instead of a computed function. It does have the side-effect of possibly firing more often than the 1000ms because each observable has a separate throttle so this may not be good for your situation. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/gdmbzk7y/)